# Swift - Reduce gap between UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

My `UICollectionViewCell` doesn't look nice even I implement autolayout and some setting in `UICollectionViewCell` inspector.

My setting is like this

[image]

My UICollectionViewCell autolayout

[image]

My ImageView autolayout

[image]

My code

PopularViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class PopularViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var users: [JSON] = []
    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of items in the section
        return users.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("UserCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PopularCollectionViewCell

        cell.user = self.users[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://128.199.160.213/datetick/users.json").responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in

            if json != nil {
                var jsonObj = JSON(json!)
                if let data = jsonObj["users"].arrayValue as [JSON]?{
                    self.users = data
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

PopularCollectionViewCell.swift

```
class PopularCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var profilePicture:UIImageView!

    var user:JSON?{
        didSet{
            self.setupUser()
        }
    }

    func setupUser(){

        if let urlString = self.user?["profilePhoto"]{
            let url = NSURL(string: urlString.stringValue)
            self.profilePicture.hnk_setImageFromURL(url!)
        }

    }
}
```

My output

[image]

Comment: A collection view will fit as many items on a line that can fit given the edge insets and the minimum inter-item spacing. To make the gaps smaller, you either need to make the cells larger, or enough smaller that one more cell can fit on a line. Is you collection view horizontal or vertical scrolling?

Comment: my collection view is horizontal scrolling. so how i can fix it?

Comment: I said how to fix it. You need to make your cells bigger. They should be (collectionView.frame.size.width - 2 * inter cell gap)/3. This assumes that you want 3 cells across.

Answer (score 0):

I know its late to reply but it might be useful for others.

You can reduce the size using UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout. You have already inherited this class in your PopularViewController

Use Following function to do so

```
//To Show 3 items per row
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.size.width - 3)/3, height: 110)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1
}
```

Comment: this helped me .. Thanks a lot.